# Trying to get an ASP.NET search thingy to work on my site

Tags: javascript, asp.net, forms

I'm working on a project that involves using the header from another organization's website on my website. There's a search feature which, if possible, I need to work on my site (although it should just trigger the search on the org's website. That is, if they type *"blah blah"* into the input and click enter, then that should open *http://www.organization_website.org/home/search-results.aspx?Search=blah+blah*). Since I know **nothing** about ASP.NET, can someone, first of all, tell me whether what I'm trying to do is possible?

I'm trying to backtrack to see what I need to include in my code for this to work. When I hover my house over the search icon, it shows *javascript:__doPostBack('dnn$dnnSEARCH$cmdSearch','')*. So I searched for the function `doPostBack(...)` and found it:

```
var theForm = document.forms['Form'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.Form;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
```

In other words, searching takes a `form` with either `id` or `name` equal to *Form*, sets the value of a few of its `input`s and then submits it. For some reason the action of the the form is set to be the page itself ....

```
<form method="post" action="/thispage.aspx" id="Form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

I don't really understand that. Anyways, I'm pretty much lost.

Comment: if i am right you want the content of the search box to be appended like this  http://www.organization_website.org/home/search-results.aspx?Search=searchbox content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i am right you can do it trough jquery

```
$(document).ready(function (){

    $('#searchbtn').click(function (e){

            window.location = 'http://www.organization_website.org/home/search-results.aspx?Search=' + $('#searchbox').val();
        //it would recirect to the url above with your search box content appended
    });
});
```

or trough your server side code inside the button click event 
in vb code

```
response.redirect("http://www.organization_website.org/home/search-results.aspx?Search=" & searchbox.text)
```